# Updating React js dependencies giving issues after upgrading them

Tags: reactjs, yarnpkg, package.json, updating, react-scripts

I am upgrading the REACT packages to the latest packages but after some error in the some package upgrade I am trying to restore the packages to the old version.

Packages to upgrade :-

```
    "react-copy-to-clipboard": "^5.0.2",
    "react-device-detect": "^1.15.0",
    "react-dnd": "^11.1.3",
    "react-dnd-html5-backend": "^11.1.3",
    "react-dom": "^16.9.0",
    "react-draggable": "^4.2.0",
    "react-dropzone": "^11.0.0",
    "react-github-btn": "^1.0.6",
    "react-helmet": "^6.1.0",
    "react-i18next": "^11.7.1",
    "react-idle-timer": "^4.5.0",
    "react-input-mask": "^2.0.4",
    "react-items-carousel": "^2.8.0",
    "react-markdown": "^7.0.1",
    "react-material-ui-form-validator": "^2.0.9",
    "react-notifications-component": "^3.0.0",
    "react-redux": "^8.0.2",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.0.1",
    "react-scripts": "^3.3.0",
    "react-slick": "^0.28.1",
    "redux": "^4.0.4",
    "redux-form": "^8.3.6",
    "redux-logger": "^3.0.6",
    "redux-mock-store": "^1.5.4",
    "redux-persist": "^6.0.0",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0",
```

to
[image: upgrade to latest]

I tried also using the

`yarn cache clean`
Removed the node_modules and also the yarn.lock files.
But its giving errors of
**process not found**